# Z_MEM_ERROR Zlib deflateInit2() embedded device

Tags: c, compression, gzip, zlib, stm32

Please mind this code:

```
  #define CHUNK 0x4000
  z_stream strm;
  unsigned char out[CHUNK];
  int ret;

  strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
  strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
  strm.opaque = Z_NULL;

  int windowsBits = 15;
  int GZIP_ENCODING = 16;

  ret = deflateInit2(&strm, Z_BEST_SPEED, Z_DEFLATED, windowsBits | GZIP_ENCODING, 1, 
                     Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
  if(ret == Z_OK) {
     strm.next_in = (z_const unsigned char *)answer;
     strm.avail_in = strlen(answer);
     do {
        strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
        strm.next_out = out;
        ret = deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
     } while (strm.avail_out == 0);
  }

    /* clean up and return */
  (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
```

With `answer` (unsigned char array of 200 elements with the last one being \0) filled in between the 4 declarations & the rest.

It crashes in the `deflateInit2` on `Z_MEM_ERROR`.

I'm working on a STM32F4 (microcontroller). My RAM was almost full (~87%) before trying to implement the compression.

I got this part working once when I used different parameters but I had an error later in the program(because I want to send the gzip'ed string to an HTTP output, error was:

> unrecognized encoding.

I have : ~30 KB of free RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib's deflate normally needs about 256K of RAM. See [zlib technical details](https://zlib.net/zlib_tech.html). 30K is a bit restrictive, but you can still get deflate to work using the `memLevel` and `windowBits` parameters to reduce the memory footprint. From that page:

```
deflate memory usage (bytes) = (1 << (windowBits+2)) + (1 << (memLevel+9))
```

So you can get there with a `memLevel` of 5, and a `windowBits` of 11, taking about 24K (plus some other structures). This will reduce the compression effectiveness somewhat, but at least it will work. (You can still add 16 to `windowBits` for gzip encoding.)

Comment: Alright, thanks, it works but I got another problem : my out buffer now has some null char in between the "normal" characters after the deflate. I used to call strlen(out buffer) . Is that normal behaviour ? Following question : I simulate streaming meaning that my string `answer` is filled multiple times. What do I have to do ? Using the deflateinit2 + deflate multiple times ? Cause it seems to only work once for now..

Comment: The result of deflate is binary data, which will have zeros with equal probability as any other byte value. You can't treat it as a "string".

Comment: You can look at [this example](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) for how to use the `deflate` and `inflate` functions.

Comment: Alright thanks. Yea I already went through it but it's not really my case cause, in the example, we get a full buffer . Meanwhile, I wanna gzip my buffers one by one (and send them right after each operation)

Comment: You need to ask a new question with more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Done, thanks for the answer : [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322449/c-loop-compression-send-gzip-zlib)